# Extending a set of named values via inheritance in scala or java

Tags: scala, enums, traits

I know a lot of questions on Enumerations and traits have been asked, however I want to start from the requirement I have to discuss the most elegant way and I realize that neither Enumeration nor trait will probably do the job..

Consider first this simple example which forms my requirement

```
trait Sound{
  def makeSound(animal: Animal.value): String
}
```

The **crucial part** is that I want programmers to be able to check the list of allowed animals by typing in "Animal.". However the list should be able to be extended by new implementations. For these reasons, following attempts failed.

**Trait implementation**

This is extendable if I define my makeSound parameter as Animal, but the programmer using the function cannot see which animals are available.

```
trait Animal
case object Dog extends Animal
case object Cat extends Animal
```

**Enumeration implementation**

This works regarding the possible values to be listed but if I want to extend it, then I need to make a new object, with a new name so it defeats the purpose.

```
object Animal extends Enumeration {
  type Animal = Value
  val Dog, Cat = Value
}
```

**Question**
As mentioned, I realize that both examples above don't meet the requirement. It is more to exclude them from the answers that I noted them down. The actual question is, how would you do this? Some options:

- file based configuration
- Let developers adjust the source code of Animal whenever they implement something new.
- What else?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at [Enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The crucial part is that I want programmers to be able to check the list of allowed animals by typing in "Animal.".

You can do it without modifying `Animal` by using implicits:

```
trait Animal
object Animal

// somewhere visible from your code
implicit class CatAnimal(singleton: Animal.type) {
  case object Cat extends Animal
}

// in your code
Animal.Cat // uses the implicit class
```

The problem is the "somewhere visible from your code" part. It could be imported, but then developer needs to know it exists to import it, which probably defeats the purpose. It could be added to an existing locaction, but then why not add it to `Animal` in the first place?

A simple solution would be to just have a common prefix for the names:

```
trait Animal
case object AnimalDog extends Animal
case object AnimalCat extends Animal
```

Then autocompletion will work fine, just type `Animal` without the `.`.

Comment: Thanks, your first suggestion is interesting and your last suggestion probably makes most sense so will probably go for the latter.